# Resizing image using Graphics.DrawImage result improperly resized image

Tags: vb.net

I want to resize an image into a **4x4 pixel image** in [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net).

Using the Internet I got this code:

```
    Public Function ResizeImage(ByVal image As Image) As Image
    Try
        Dim newWidth = 4
        Dim newHeight = 4

        Dim newImage As New Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight)
        newImage.SetResolution(100, 100)

        Using graphicsHandle As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)
            graphicsHandle.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
            graphicsHandle.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)
        End Using

        Return newImage

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return image
    End Try
End Function
```

Original:

[image: image1]

Resized with photoshop(the real way of resizing it):

[image: image2]

using `InterpolationMode.Bilinear`

[image: image3]

using `InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic`

[image: image4]

What is the problem ?

Comment: `Catch ex As Exception : Return image` is a possible problem. I suggest you temporarily remove the `Try/Catch` block (and `Return image`) to see if your code throws any exceptions. Currently you wouldn't know if it did, which might cause it to return the same image (if that is what you're experiencing).

Comment: @VisualVincent It have nothing to do with it, i also used a msgbox to check if it catch any errors and it don't

Comment: ...so the *real* question is not that the size is incorrect - they do appear to be 4x4 - but rather you dont like the interpolation and deem PhotoShop to be the only "right" way"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings you'll want are bilinear or bicubic interpolation (avoid the "high-quality" options) and PixelOffsetMode.Half.

```
graphicsHandle.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.Bilinear
graphicsHandle.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half
```

When interpolating, GDI+ normally offsets the center of the pixel by a half pixel. This can have an undesirable effect when scaling, with the appearance of shifting the scaled image up and left. Using PixelOffsetMode.Half shifts the pixels back where they "belong".

The high-quality bilinear and bicubic interpolation modes appear to blend the edge pixels with hypothetical transparent pixels beyond the image bounds, creating a fringe of semi-transparency at the edges.

Comment: Very good answer, it did the trick and also good explication !